# Cannot add foreign key in InnoDB

Tags: mysql

In phpMyAdmin when i try to add foreign key some error occurs and does not tell what is wrong. Just says "FK fails".

Can any one tell what is the problem?

```
Error

SQL query:

ALTER TABLE `hotel` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `type_id` ) REFERENCES `hotel`.`hotel_type` (
`id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hotel`.`#sql-cfc_e`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-cfc_e_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `hotel_type` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a foreign key that links to the same table? A foreign key is a link to a foreign table (some table other than hotel). What are you trying to do?

Comment: basically I have a table for categories for hotel and i am adding category table primary key into hotel table

Comment: it does not accept foregn key from any table

Comment: Sorry I mis-spoke, was looking at database name instead of table name.

Comment: Could you add just the part which causes error (without error details) @RiazKhan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure the columns of both tables are of the same data-type:

```
hotel.hotel type_id int(11) unsigned # type_id column of hotel table

hotel.hotel_type id int(11) unsigned # id column of hotel_type table
```

If they are not of the same type then you won't be able to add your FK constraint.

-- Edit --

Based on your response, the columns are the same data-types, so that means you have an invalid value in the `hotels.type_id` column (value doesn't exist in the `hotel_types` table). Check the values in your `hotels.type_id` column and make sure they exist in your `hotel_types.id` column.

Answer (score 2):

Well there can be a lot of reasons for which you can't create a foreign key. I have found a very interesting [article](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/), which I suggest you to read it closely. Maybe something will help you. You can also find very important infos in the MySQL manual, regarding the "[FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)".

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

There are some data in your table that no longer exist in other table, and actually this is against foreign key rules.

If you don't need their data, truncate both tables, and add the foreign key otherwise you should add all the foreign keys one by one.

Here is a query that will find those rows:

> select sourcecode_id from
>
> sourcecodes_tags tags left join sourcecodes sc on tags.sourcecode_id=sc.id
>
> where sc.id is null;

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

Although this is old, I thought I would share that the way I resolved this was by checking that the encoding and the collation were the same on both sides which for some reason were different.

This fixed the issue.